# What are the benefits of a closure, and when are they typically used?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm a web developer, but lots of folks are looking for slightly more advanced skills and understanding closures seems to be at the forefront of this.

I get the whole "execution context creating a reference to a variable that doesnt ever get destroyed" thing, but really, is this some sort of private or static variable implementation in JavaScript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They can be good for lots of things, for example, visibility (like private members in traditional OO).

```
var count = function(num) {

   return function(add) {
       add = add || 1;
       num += add;
       return num;
   }

}
```

[See it](http://jsbin.com/onuya3/edit).

My `count()` can be seeded with a number. When I assign a variable to the return, I can call it with an optional number to add to the internal `num` (an argument originally, but still part of the scope of the returned function).

[This is a pretty good overview](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

#### See also on Stack Overflow

- [What is a practical use for a closure in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript)
- [How does a javascript closure work ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work)
- [When actually is a closure created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780428/when-actually-is-a-closure-created)
- [more...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+closure)

Comment: When are they typically used?

Comment: @codeninja Check out the links at the bottom. They helped me when I was exactly in your position a short while ago.

Answer (score 5):

A closure is a code block with bound variables - it "catches" its variables from their outer context - but it is independent from that same context.

A practical use in javascript is when defining events or callbacks - you declare a closure to be executed on the click of a button, for instance, but this closure can reference variables declared on the caller scope.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) uses closures a lot - btw this is a good link for understanding closures for jQuery: [A Graphical Explanation Of Javascript Closures In A jQuery Context](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1482-A-Graphical-Explanation-Of-Javascript-Closures-In-A-jQuery-Context.htm).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are many JS books available, but you really should grab a copy of David Flanagan's [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996) if you really want to *learn* this (still the best JS reference IMHO). Read the chapter on closures and you'll get a lot more in-depth knowledge than anyone can give you in a reply here.

Comment: The question is asking for specific topic if you can elaborate here. If posted a description with a good example could help a lot.